# CORS error when running Angular app from VS2017

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, cors

I'm trying to run a .net core angular project from VS2017, but I get this error in Chrome (and Firefox). Does anybody know what it means? The solution works perfectly on colleagues PC.

```
Failed to load https://unpkg.com/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js: Redirect from 'https://unpkg.com/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js' to 'https://unpkg.com/@angular/core@5.0.0/bundles/core.umd.js' has been 
blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. Origin 'http://localhost:27407' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I'm thinking that it is some package that is not updated correctly, but I have tried all update tricks that I can think of to no avail.

Comment: What does the headers of the PHP look like?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by the 'PHP'? I have allowed CORS and tried running Chrome without security.

Comment: How did you allow CORS, i asked about PHP because I have run into this issue because of the cross origin policy javascript has, so without express permission to access another sites data by that site you cannot access it and get a similar error as the one you have recieved

Comment: My thought is that "magic" tries to upgrade some dependency, but fails to download. But npm and package.json is new to me, so I dont understand it yet.